# how to store the user input in a parameter in dialogflow

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have a Intent where I have a parameter called **age** and its value I want it to be the user input.

And in the response I would like to responde with the same input as user given ex:

```
User Input: Hello, haw are you.
Bot: You said: Hello, haw are you.
```

So I would need the user input first to store in a parameter and from the Text Response section I can call the parameter but I just don't know how to catch the user input at this moment!

So Text response would be like: `You said: $input.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show user input on Response section in Dialogflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923322/how-can-i-show-user-input-on-response-section-in-dialogflow)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Javascript, you can find many useful details [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client).

Depending on the way you get the input, the solution is totally different. 
For instance, in [this link](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-javascript-client/blob/master/demo/typescript-project/src/Application.ts) you get the input via a click (this.button.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick.bind(this))) or in the following code you get the input as a query.

```
import {ApiAiClient} from "api-ai-javascript";
import {IRequestOptions, IServerResponse, ApiAiConstants} from "api-ai-javascript/ApiAiClient"
const client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken: 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'})

queryInput.addEventListener("keydown", queryInputKeyDown);

.textRequest('Hello!')
    .then((response) => {console.log(queryInput.value);})
```

Thus, in the above example, you can use:

`value = queryInput.value`

Comment: im not using javascript, nothing, can't I get the user input directly from DialogFlow on the response section?

Comment: You mean in the console (https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/)? AFAIK it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it in Inline Editor Fulfillment

```
function userInput(agent) {
   let user_input = agent.query;
 //test it
   agent.add(user_input);
}
```