# How can I show user input on Response section in Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I would like to print out user input on a Response Section but for some reason I cannot seem to find how can I do this.

For example:

```
Bot: How old are you?
User: 40
Bot: Your age is 40.
```

I am also attaching a screenshot where I have a parameter but I just dont know to what to assing age.
[image]

Currently I get Your age is 100 as I manually added 100 as a value to age parameter. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 5):

To get the input from user you have to capture that age value in an entity. You can either use a system entity or create your own, but for your case to capture "age" **sys.number-integer** can be perfect!

Just add a training phrase in the intent as template phrase (see that **"@"** at the left), just click on the default **"** symbol beside the training phrase to switch to template mode as it will suit best for your need of matching age.

**Training phrase:**
[image]
**Parameter:**
[image]
**Response:**
[image]

**Edit:** for getting name(text) input you have to use @sys.any entity (make sure that you are using template mode (@) and not example mode("))

**Training phrase & parameter:**
[image]
**Response:**
[image]

Comment: i have cases where input can be strings, like whats your name!

Comment: there are different system entities to handle such normal data, for names or text you can use "@sys.any" (just type @ in the training phrase box n you will have options to choose from available system entities

Comment: i tried to add '@sys.any' on training and in param i have any as parameter and @sys.any as entity value is $any but it does not seem to work

Comment: in training phrase it will be @sys.any:name, in param "name" as parameter and in response $name

Comment: i tried as u said, not working, actually it is not responding at all now.

Comment: what did you enter in all the three places for name intent

Comment: i just entered @sys.any:name on training and name as parameter, name as value, can u provide some example?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot with what you tried and isn't working. "Not responding at all now" makes it sound like something else went wrong.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @Prisoner, please add screenshot so that we can get some idea, btw I have edited the answer for name queries